# How to just compile only changed (or related) module in multi-module gradle project

Tags: scala, gradle, build, multi-module

I am having multi-module gradle project, which is having 5 modules. And these modules creates a lineage of dependency ie. **A** <- **B** <- **C** <- **D** <- **E**.

Here **A** depends on **B**, **B** depends on **C** and so on.

My problem is that, If i am going to change in **A**, it compile all the parent modules.

Is there any way to just compile only **A**. And if i change in **B** then only compile **A** and **B**.

Comment: If it recompiles  everything when you only change A, then either you're not understanding what gradle says correctly, or you asking gradle to actually recompile everything, or you have a big mistake in your gradle build file, or your dependencies aren't actually what you claim they are, or the gradle scala compile task has a bug. But I really doubt the last explantion is the right one. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Show what you're doing to draw that conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @JB Nizet you are correct i was using one of the **scalaCompileOption** property.

```
  tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.with {
      force = true
    }
```

which force to disable scala incremental build.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#sec:scala_incremental_compilation