# Understanding of Multi-modular project android

Tags: android, kotlin, modular-design, modulation

I have three modules in my project say ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC. My problem is when i run the project every time all the three module getting recompiled irrespective of the changes made in the module,
But what i found in some of the blog is that only the changes affected module will compiled remaining modules will be cached, But i am not able achieve that behaviour.
**Example**
  ModuleA is dependent on B and C, and B and C are independent modules.

ModuleA **build.gradle**

```
  dependencies {
   implementation project (‘ModuleB’) 
   implementation project (‘ModuleC’)   
}
```

In the above case i made some changes only in ModuleC which is not dependent on any other module, but though ModuleA and ModuleB is compiled.
can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: You should look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670130/how-to-just-compile-only-changed-or-related-module-in-multi-module-gradle-proj

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to just compile only changed (or related) module in multi-module gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670130/how-to-just-compile-only-changed-or-related-module-in-multi-module-gradle-proj)